# What's the benefit of Object.freeze() not freezing objects within the passed object?

Tags: javascript

I was learning more about the methods of JavaScript's `Object` constructor on MDN and I noticed that the last sentence of [**Object.freeze's description**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) reads:

> Note that values that are objects can still be modified, unless they are also frozen.

A behavior like that seems like it should be opt-in. What exactly is the benefit of having to manually freeze a frozen object's objects recursively?

#### If I'm freezing an object, why would I want the objects inside of it to still be mutable?

Comment: I think it is correct behavior. Moreover you can modify the implementation to recursively freeze child objects if any.

Comment: This is asking for opinions. If you want to ask about why ECMAScript is the way it is, please talk to the people who work on it and discuss it every day on [ES–Discuss](https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/es-discuss).

Comment: It is like, you can freeze a `man` object from having more children or disowning any he already has. But you can't prevent his children from growing (age++).

Comment: @techfoobar that metaphor explanation was beautiful.

Comment: Incidentally, Objects only hold *references* to other objects, so you may freeze an object that is also "inside" some other object (or many other objects).

Comment: @techfoobar And you can't stop the `man`'s `children` from having children of their own. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer lies in the point itself

```
Note that values that are objects can still be modified, unless they are also frozen.
```

**Update:**

> There is no official information any where regarding the design decision of freeze() method

I think, basically for **performance reasons** they have took this decision, if we have wanted to make the internal objects also freezed, we would have to apply the **method recursively**. So this is a big overhead, so the design decision was made to avoid this.

> **If it was not the performance, the method would have behaved
>   differently.**

Comment: "Basically for performance reasons they have took this decision". Do you have a reference for that, or is it just your opinion?

Comment: @RobG Its implicit as per mdn note. I did not find any official reference.

Comment: Implicit in what note? The quote just states a fact. The people who contribute to MDN do not necessarily (and mostly don't) have anythig to do with either JavaScript or ECMAScript specifications.

Comment: @RobG I explained what I thought in the form of answer. Thats all I understood from their (mdn) notes. If it was not the performance, the method would have behaved differently. I agree with you regarding MDN.

Comment: So your "answer" should start with "I think it's because…". There are other good reasons for not making *freeze* recursive. ES–Discuss is a much better forum to ask this question since that is where people who are involved day–to–day in the development and mainteinance of ECMAScript hang out. They are much more likely to really know why.

Comment: @RobG Updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @KostaKontos Your link would have to include a test that uses `Object.freeze`  recursively if you want to dispute the answer, which was comparing only freezing an object's properties to recursive freezing. And that depends on how many objects are nested in the root object.

Answer (score 13):

I think if recursive is the default strategy, some complex Objects could not behave as expected.
Think about following situation:

```
<div id="root">
    <div id="stem">
        <div id="leaf>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and for some reason I want to freeze the `stem`, so I wrote these code:

```
Object.freeze(document.getElementById('stem'));
```

If it freezes recursively, the `leaf` would be frozen too, and it seems OK: if I want to freeze the `stem`, I also want to freeze it's children.

But wait, note that `stem` has another property -- It has `parentElement` too. So what will happen? When I freeze `stem`, I also freeze `stem.parentElement`, and `stem.parentElement.parentElement`... This is never what I want.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it more, it's probably to prevent the freezing of referenced objects that  are also being referenced elsewhere (thus disabling another section of code that uses the same object). My response to that would be:

I wasn't suggesting it work that way. `Object.freeze()` would make more sense if the state of the object is captured completely. The references (to the objects) themselves could be immutable, but the object referenced would not be frozen.

If I did this...

```
var friend = {
    name: 'Alec',
    likes: {
        programming: true,
        reading: true,
        cooking: false
    }
};

// Pass as frozen object
doStuff(Object.freeze(friend));

document.addEventListener('click', function () {
    friend.likes.clicking = true;
});
```

...it would make sense that I don't want `name` to be changed **AND** I don't want the friend's `likes` to be changed by `doStuff()`. But I would still want to be able to change `likes` (just like I could change `name`) from an event listener, for example, without `doStuff()`'s object reference to `friend` changing too.

**Edit:** After reading Shaik's answer, I understand why they do it the way they do. Now, in order to have the functionality I would need in this example, I would do this:

```
function deepFreeze (obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object') return console.error('An object must be passed to deepFreeze()');
    for (var key in obj) {
        var val = obj[key];
        if (typeof val === 'object') deepFreeze(val);
    }
    return Object.freeze(obj);
}
```

Are there any inherent problems with this?

Comment: Re: "Are there any inherent problems with this?"

Yes, a minor one: `typeof null == 'object'` is true (I assume the person responsible for this is hiding off the grid now). So `null` will get passed to `Object.freeze` but will cause an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object.freeze called on non-object`. All you need is a null check though.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the situation. You may want to freeze an object to prevent a new property set from being added, or being remove, however you may want existing properties to be altered. If you don't, just freeze them! IIRC, you can only freeze the parent object. Child objects would need a recursive freeze as well.